# Bulk action to remove values in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have these documents:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:9200/jerewan/product/_search?pretty" -d'
{
    {"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"product"}}
    {"id_product":"1", "categories":[1,2], "enums":[10,11,20,21] }
    {"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"product"}}
    {"id_product":"2", "categories":[1,2], "enums":[10,15,25,26] }
    {"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"product"}}
    {"id_product":"3", "categories":[2,3], "enums":[11,12,13,21,22,23,24] }

}
```

I need to remove numbers 10 and 11 in enums field in all documents with bulk action.

So, output will be after this update:

```
 {"id_product":"1", "categories":[1,2], "enums":[20,21] }
 {"id_product":"2", "categories":[1,2], "enums":[15,25,26] }
 {"id_product":"3", "categories":[2,3], "enums":[12,13,21,22,23,24]
```

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:9200/jerewan/product/_search?pretty" -d'
{
    { "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "product", "_index" : "test"} }
    { "doc" : {"enums" : [20,21]} }
    { "update" : {"_id" : "2", "_type" : "product", "_index" : "test"} }
    { "doc" : {"enums" : [15,25, 26]} }
}
```

using this you can update for further read [bulk api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-bulk.html)